# Aggregation $cond if condition implementation in Java

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I nedded to implement 'if condition'in java i don't know how to do that,So give some suggestion  to that

```
db.test.aggregate(
       [
          {
             $project:
               {
                 data: 1,
                 result:
                   {
                     $cond: { if: { $cond: [ "$salary", 250000 ] }, then: 30, else: 20 }
                   }
               }
          }
       ]
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just [`Documents`](http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/org/bson/Document.html) and `List`s

```
List<Document> pipeline = Arrays.asList(
  new Document("$project",
    new Document("data1", 1)
      .append("result", new Document(
        "$cond", new Document(
          "if", new Document("$eq", Arrays.asList("$salary", 250000) )
        )
        .append("then", 30)
        .append("else", 20) 
      ))
  )
);
```

Serializes as:

```
[
  { "$project": {
    "data1": 1,
    "result": {
      "$cond": {
        "if": { "$eq": [ "$salary", 250000 ] },
        "then": 30,
        "else": 20
      }
    }
  }}
]
```

Or alternately using the "list" form of [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/):

```
List<Document> pipeline = Arrays.asList(
  new Document("$project",
    new Document("data1", 1)
      .append("result", new Document(
        "$cond", Arrays.asList(
          new Document("$eq", Arrays.asList("$salary", 250000) ),
          30,
          20
        )
      ))
  )
);
```

Serializes as:

```
[
  { "$project": {
    "data1": 1,
    "result": {
      "$cond": [
        { "$eq": [ "$salary", 250000 ] },
        30,
        20
      }
    }
  }}
]
```

Both are valid usages of [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/).

Also noting the error in your question, you might mean [`$eq`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/) or you might mean [`$gt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gt/) or other logical operator on the condition. [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) expects it's "if" to return a boolean.

Depending on the driver you might interchange [`Document`](http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/org/bson/Document.html) with [`BasicDBObject`](http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/com/mongodb/BasicDBObject.html) instead.